# Create collision map from Kinect with nodelet

Tags: kinect, octomap, nodelet, collision-map, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I use a camera Kinect for create a collision map but currently it's too slow and use 100% CPU. So I want use nodelets to avoid useless copies of pointCloud and speed up the process.
I understand how I should use nodelet with openni_launch because I have a good explaining here: [Get start with ROS Nodelet](http://www.embeddedheaven.com/ros-nodelet.htm)

My question is How create a collision map with nodelet ?
Currently I use octomap_server to construct the map but it's not a nodelet.

It's necessary to modify the package ocotomap_server to porting nodes to nodelets ?

Or it's possible to run this node as nodelets with a change in the launch file ?

Or existing other package to construct collision map with nodelets ?

Thanks

EDIT:

I have tried with two computer: (With system Monitor)

The first work with two CPU at 100%: Ubuntu 10.04 / Ros Electric / Memory 3.9 GiB / Two processor Intel Core(TM)2 6600 @ 2.40GHz

The second work well, it have only a CPU at 100%, it have 8 CPU: Unbuntu 12.04 / Ros Electric / Memory 15.7 GiB / Height processor Intel(R)Xeon(R) W3565 @ 3.20 GHz

EDIT 2:
New subject on how create this node: [Build a octomap_server nodelet](http://answers.ros.org/question/40948/build-a-octomap_server-nodelet/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39329/create-collision-map-from-kinect-with-nodelet/) by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-07-19**:
You have no tags on your question, it is unlikely to be found by people who know about these things

**Comment by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on 2012-07-22**:
Yes it's true. Now that's good. thank you

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-22**:
What are the specs (CPU type, speed, RAM, etc) of the computer you are trying to create the collision map on?

**Comment by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on 2012-07-22**:
I have did a EDIT. A other question, We will soon use Fuerte. Is there a change between Electric and Fuerte with octomap_server ? It's for know if my work on electric can be used on Fuerte without change.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-07-22**:
New (unrelated) questions tend to get lost in comments, but nevertheless: see the Changelog: http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap_mapping/ChangeList

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-07-22**:
In general, the Fuerte version got a few new features and will be worked on, while electric will stay as it is. There should not be a change for you, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you would need to write your own Nodelet using octomap_server. That should be easily possible, since you can just internally use the OctomapServer class (C++ API instead of ROS node API).

However, I would guess that most of the CPU load comes from expensive map updates and ray casting, instead of pointcloud serialization/deserialization. A Nodelet would not speed up much in that case, but it might be worth a try.

Note that octomap_server outputs detailed timing on the debug log level, so you can estimate the time it takes to just insert the pointclouds into the map.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on 2012-07-22**:
Ok
I will try to write my own nodelet with the OctomapServer class.
Now I work with a computer with 8 CPU more efficient (Before 2 CPU) but we want improve the speed a maximum. I think the copy of the pointCloud between node is expensive also.
Very useful a tool to estimate time, thx

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-07-22**:
There is no parallelization in octomap or octomap_server, so for that case only the specs of a single CPU will count.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Only loosely related, but you could set the kinect to QVGA (e.g. using dynamic_reconfigure). This will decrease the cloud resolution very efficiently.

You can also use a voxel grid filter or filter out far points (passthrough filter).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on 2012-07-22**:
Yes I also work on the quality of point cloud. The resolution is the more efficiently to reduce the time. I want also select a region of point cloud to limit the size. I don't know the voxel grid filter out far points. Is used for that? Have you more detail of this ? It's in openni launch ?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-07-23**:
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/voxel_grid.php